# What are the problem with running binary classification on panel data using logistic regression?

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, classification, cart, bagging

I am a newbie and I am trying to understand why one cannot run algorithms like logistic regression or decision trees on panel dataset ?

I am running an employee attrition model where the dependent variable is 1 when the employee has quit the organisation voluntarily, 0 otherwise.

The data is recorded quarterly, although not all features change every quarter, such as the gender.

If I have 4 years (2021 - 2024) worth of quarterly data, I will 16 rows for an employee who is till with the organisation with dependent variable as 0 for all rows. If the employee has quit in the first quarter of the first year considered i.e. 2020, there will only one row for the employee and the dependent variable will be 1. If the employee quit in the 4th quarter of 2024, we will have 16 rows out of which 15 rows will have independent variable as 0 and the 16th row corresponding to the last quarter of 2024 as 1.

Given the above data structure, is it ok to consider each row independent when we include time (year-quarter) as a feature ? We do have performance measure for each quarter. Wondering if we can run logistic regression on the above dataset, if not why ? If it is violating IID, how ? Because not all the rows for an employee have dependent variable as 1, just the quarter in which he or she quit. So can we consider this to be IID ? If not what are the implications of running logistic regression or decision tree on a panel dataset such as above ?

Kindly help me understand.